# Проблема с выбором, пункта из выпадающего списка

Tags: php

После выбора пункта из выпадающего списка, данный пункт не сохраняется в поле, так же в форма сформированный вопрос не отправляет. В чем может быть проблема

```
<form class="block-section feedback" action="http://test.ru" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <h2 class="second-heading-section">Форма обращения</h2>
  <div class="dropdown input">
    <input type="checkbox" class="dropdown__switch visually-hidden" id="filter-switch" />
    <label for="filter-switch" class="dropdown__options-filter">
      <div class="dropdown__filter" role="listbox" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="dropdown__filter-selected" aria-selected="true">Тема сообщения</div>
        <div class="dropdown__select">
          <div class="dropdown__select-option" role="option">Тест1</div>
          <div class="dropdown__select-option" role="option">Тест2</div>
          <div class="dropdown__select-option last-tape" role="option">Тест3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input"><input class="input__field" type="text" name="Имя" required="" />
    <lable for="name" class="input__label">Ваше имя</lable>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="input__field tel selector" type="tel" name="Телефон" pattern="[\+]\d{1}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2}" minlength="16" maxlength="16" onfocus="(!this.value.length ? this.value='+7 ' : this.value=this.value)" />
    <lable for="tel" class="input__label">Телефон</lable><span class="form-error">Это обязательное поле. Введите телефон в формате +7 999 999-99-99</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="input__field email" type="email" name="Почта" required="" />
    <lable for="email" class="input__label">Электронная почта</lable>
    <span class="form-error">Неправильный формат. Введите электронный почтовый адрес в формате text@mail.ru</span>
  </div>
  <textarea class="textarea" cols="40" rows="10" name="Вопрос" type="textarea" placeholder="Ваш вопрос"></textarea>
  <div class="form-files">
    <div class="form-file">
      <div class="form-file-input">Прикрепить файл <input type="file" name="form_file_24" /></div>
      <div class="form-file-name">
        <div class="form-file-name-remove"></div>
        <div class="form-file-name-text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fedback-area">
    <input class="inside-btn feedback__btn" type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение" />
    <span class="checkbox__footnote">Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку персональных данных и принимаете политику конфиденциальности</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот хоть убейте, но не вижу здесь ни одной строчки PHP кода.